# Xcode Debugger Swift: Not able to view value of variables in debugger and lldb command gives error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11.3

I am facing issues with Xcode - Version 11.3.1. When I try to debug the code getting below error when code stops on the debugger point.

```
/Users/dhavalkansara/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-eyrexmpjkcwrmggjgqgxkfyogvgk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Runner: Cannot load Swift type information; AST validation error in "Runner": The module file format is too old to be used by this version of the debugger.
Cannot create Swift scratch context (couldn't load the Swift stdlib)Cannot create Swift scratch context (couldn't load the Swift stdlib)Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
Shared Swift state for Runner could not be initialized.
The REPL and expressions are unavailable.
```

- When I tried to print variable value using **lldb** `po varName` and also no values are visible for variable on the left-hand side in below screenshot:

[image]

I have already tried below steps but still facing the same error for all projects:

- Deleted derived data
- Clean build
- Restarted Xcode